# repaint only happens at the end of my loop - java

Tags: java, frame, repaint

basically I'm making TRON and my first step is to make a basic snake game and my first step is to make a square move down the screen and then implement key listeners. i want to see the square moving down at every stage stage but i just seem to get the final paint image, so i think it does move, i just don't see the frame being updated, can anyone help?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.*;


public class Multiplayer extends JPanel { //implements ActionListener {


    public static Multiplayer multiplayer;
    public static ArrayList<Point> bikeParts = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final int UP = 0, DOWN = 1, LEFT = 2, RIGHT = 3, SCALE = 10;
    public static int ticks = 0, direction = DOWN;
    public static Point bike;
    public boolean over = false;
    public JFrame frame;
    public renderPanel rp;

    public Multiplayer() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        //JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        rp = new renderPanel();
        //add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(rp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(900, 700);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        bike = new Point(0, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            animate(null);
            rp.repaint();
        }
    }

    //@Override
    public void animate(ActionEvent ef) {
        rp.repaint();
        ticks++;
        System.out.println("yw");
        if (ticks % 10 == 0 && bike != null && over != true) {
            System.out.println("did");
            rp.repaint();
            bikeParts.add(new Point(bike.x, bike.y));
            if (direction == UP) {
                if (bike.y - 1 > 0) {

                    bike = new Point(bike.x, bike.y - 1);
                } else {
                    over = true;
                }
            }
            if (direction == DOWN) {
                if (bike.y + 1 < 700) {
                    bike = new Point(bike.x, bike.y + 1);
                } else {
                    over = true;
                }
            }
            if (direction == LEFT) {
                if (bike.x - 1 > 0) {
                    bike = new Point(bike.x - 1, bike.y);
                } else {
                    over = true;
                }
                bike = bikeParts.get(bikeParts.size() - 1);
                bikeParts.remove(0);
            }
            if (direction == RIGHT) {
                if (bike.x + 1 < 900) {
                    bike = new Point(bike.x + 1, bike.y);
                } else {
                    over = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class renderPanel extends JComponent {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("painting");
        Multiplayer mp = Multiplayer.multiplayer;

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 900, 700);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 900, 700);  //arena

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        for (Point point : mp.bikeParts) {
            g.fillRect(point.x * Multiplayer.SCALE, point.y * Multiplayer.SCALE, Multiplayer.SCALE, Multiplayer.SCALE);
        }
        g.fillRect(mp.bike.x * Multiplayer.SCALE, mp.bike.y * Multiplayer.SCALE, Multiplayer.SCALE, Multiplayer.SCALE);
    }
}
```

Comment: You start the next animation step as soon as a step has finished. Your 1000 steps are so fast you only see the last one.

Comment: Better use a swing **Timer**.

Comment: @StephaneM if i change it, it only draws it up to that point, so 500 only draws the square half way, but it doesn't then update again

Comment: @StephaneM so the problem is the fact the repaint is the last thing called

Comment: As Joop Eggen said you should use a timer so that you can wait between 2 repaints. You only need to repaint at most 25 or 50 times per second.

Comment: @sb33 Go read [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for the cause of your problem and the go read [Using Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for the most common solution